# Unable to pass a sentence in a list of strings using extra-vars in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Background:

I have an Ansible utility that will take new comments as `extra-vars` from the users and add them to `/etc/motd` in the comments section. These comments are first stored in local facts file in the form of an array. My code then iterates through this and writes each comment in a new line. However, this works only for a single-word comment but not for an entire sentence.

Input format:

```
/opt/companyname/ansible/bin/ansible-pull -U /remote/osreleases/git-repo/xxx-ansible -i "localhost," -C beta -d /u/subburat/xxx-ansible push-full.yml -f --extra-vars '{"common_motd_qsc_add_comment": ["comment3","comment4"]}' -t common_motd_qsc
```

main.yml

```
- name: Add a new comment if it does not exist
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | union([t_new_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ common_motd_qsc_add_comment }}"
  when:
    - t_new_entry not in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
    - t_new_entry|length > 0
  vars:
    t_new_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"

- name: Save comments to snps.fact file
  ini_file:
    dest: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/snps.fact"
    section: 'motd'  # [header]
    option: 'common_motd_qsc_comment_array'  # key
    value: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array }}"  # value

- name: Create /etc/motd
  template:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/templates/motd"
    dest: "{{ common_motd_qsc_os_motd_file }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
```

`/etc/motd` file after running the input command (single word comment). Note that comment3 and commen4 are added in the comments section.

```
  Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
  OS:        CentOS7.3
  Hostname:  host001 (xxxx)
  Location:  Cagexxx
  CPU:       16  x 2599 MHz, Intel(R) Xeon(R) (2 socket, 8 core, No HT)
  Memory:    126 GB RAM, 126 GB Swap
  QSC:       QSC-S
  Comments:
            Warning:  This machine binding LDAP instead of NIS
            comment3
            comment4
  Note: Please do NOT edit this file directly. Use ansible utility to add or delete comment(s).
```

When I run the same input but this time trying to add a longer comment (sentence), it throws me an error.

Input (sentence):

```
/opt/companyname/ansible/bin/ansible-pull -U /remote/osreleases/git-repo/xxx-ansible -i "localhost," -C beta -d /u/subburat/xxx-ansible push-full.yml -f --extra-vars '{"common_motd_qsc_add_comment": ["This is a long comment"]}' -t common_motd_qsc
```

Error:

```
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]
ERROR! Ext
Define anraneous opd run a sitions or angle task rguments
'playbook' against a set of hosts
ERROR! the playbook: ** could not be found
```

It means that the second word which is "is" in the sentence "This is a long comment" is causing trouble. Any help on this greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The issue was with the quotes in my input. No change in the code was required.

**Note:**  If the input is a sentence (with spaces), make sure that you pay attention to the quotes. There is a double quote (") within the single quotes (').

```
/opt/companyname/ansible/bin/ansible-pull -U /remote/osreleases/git-repo/xxx-ansible -i "localhost," -C beta -d /u/subburat/xxx-ansible push-full.yml -f --extra-vars='{"common_motd_qsc_add_comment": ['"This is a long sentence with spaces"',"comment5"]}' -t common_motd_qsc
```